# check that values not null

Tags: sql, mysql

How I can rewrite following query that I will take minus `Correction` and `Used` only when they are not null.

```
select Amount - Correction - Used 
    from CompList 
    where (CompID ='D999999' and  Amount IS NOT NULL) ;
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the COALESCE function (which returns the first non-null value):

```
select Amount - COALESCE(Correction, 0) - COALESCE(Used, 0) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function IFNULL(field, 0).
It could be faster than COALESCE : you must test ...